# netrw ftp error ("Unknown command^M"; "Line 245:" "E517: No buffers were wiped out: 8bw!"

Tags: netrw

Until a few days ago, **editing remote files** worked perfectly OK, but not any more, with strange messages and error windows showing up:

#### a) Loading remote file:

When I'm trying to load a remote file with

`:e ftp://username@ftp.example.co.uk/test.html`, the file loads ok, but the window is minimised to 1 line and
**another large window opens with** the text

```
Unknown command^M
```

`:messages` gives me:

```
   "NetrwMessage" --No lines in buffer-- 
   "~\AppData\Local\Temp\VIAEB5B.html" [unix] 406L,6899C
```

I have to close the `Unknown command^M`-window with `:bd!`

#### b) Saving to remote file:

When I try to write back to ftp location with

`:w ftp://username@ftp.example.co.uk/test.html`

another window opens (again) with

```
Unknown command^M
```

and `:messages` gives me:

```
"NetrwMessage" --No lines in buffer--
"~\AppData\Local\Temp\VIAEB5B.html" [unix] 406L,6899C
"NetrwMessage" --No lines in buffer--
Error detected while processing function netrw#NetWrite:
line 245:
E517: No buffers were wiped out: 8bw!
"[No Name]" [Modified] 1 line --100%--
```

#### My system (at work)

**Windows** 10 Enterprise Version 1809 OS build 17763.1339
(but have no admin rights on this work PC, and cmd.exe disabled...). I'm on VIM version 8.2 with the same **vimrc** (which is the same as on my computer at home running Ubuntu where there are no problems).

#### Please help

I've reinstalled vim8.2 which made no difference.
I saw whilst googling that `bw` is interpreted as **buffer wipe**, but have no idea where this is coming from, and inspection of `netrw.vim` line 245 doesn't help me either.

Any help would be appreciated.